# javaFX - creating smooth animation without creating a new Thread

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I have a car in my javaFX project where the position of the car(Node) should change(the car should jump smoothly) when SPACE is pressed . so I have used an event handler which invokes a method named :`moveUp()`

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            switch (event.getCode())
            {
                case SPACE:
                    moveUp();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

This creates a new Thread where the speed of the car is changed 10 times with an interval of 75 milliseconds.

```
private void moveUp() {
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           carSpeed = 10;
           for(;carSpeed>=0;carSpeed--)
           {
               try {
                   Thread.currentThread().sleep(75);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               carPosition_X+=carSpeed;
               carPosition_Y-=carSpeed;
               car.relocate(carPosition_X,carPosition_Y);
           }
           for(carSpeed=0;carSpeed<=10;carSpeed++)
           {
               try {
                   Thread.currentThread().sleep(75);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               carPosition_X+=carSpeed;
               carPosition_Y+=carSpeed;
               car.relocate(carPosition_X,carPosition_Y);
           }
       }
   }).start();
}
```

This code is doing like this (pressing SPACE once and jumping the car):
[image]

If I don't use a different thread the GUI thread will be freeze and if I don't use Thread.sleep() the car will jump abruptly(not smoothly). This code is doing well . But I have learnt that `thread.start()` doesn't guarantee immediate execution of the thread. How can I guarantee immediate execution ?

Comment: as far as i know, you cannot guarantee immediate execution because this are physical limits. but: remove the Thread.sleep() and use the delta time in each loop execution to calculate the amount the car should move.

Comment: Take a look at the [`javafx.animation` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/package-frame.html); [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) is probably most suitable class...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to stay in the FX Application Thread and to use the class `AnimationTimer`. Here is a short demo for a smooth jump:

```
private void moveUp() {
        new AnimationTimer() {
            long startTime = -1;
            double initCarPosition_Y;                

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                if(startTime == -1){
                    startTime = now;
                    initCarPosition_Y = carPosition_Y;
                    carSpeedX = 3d;
                    carSpeedY = -15d;                                   
                }                   

                double time = (now - startTime) / 1E9d;
                carPosition_X += carSpeedX * time;  
                carPosition_Y += carSpeedY * time;
                if(carSpeed > 0 && initCarPosition_Y <= carPosition_Y){
                    carPosition_Y = initCarPosition_Y;
                    stop();
                }
                carSpeedY += 0.8d * time; //gravity

                car.relocate(carPosition_X, carPosition_Y);                 
            }
        }.start();
}
```

This approach gives you full and direct control over what happens in every single frame. However, javaFX also provides high level animation classes including predefined interpolators and transitions. Suitable for alternative approaches could be the following classes:

- `PathTransition`: Allows you to define points and curves which a given node is animated along.
- `TimeLine`: Allows you to define arbitrary animation key frames based on properties like the position of a node.

Note that generally working with these high level classes could become challenging when you want to animate an user controlled actor like your car. These classes all take an exact duration for the animation to last. For example when you want to translate a node as long as a specific key is pressed, you don't know the duration of the animation in beforehand.